# Should I use 'not x' or 'x == 0' to check to see if the result of a modulo operation is zero in python

Tags: python

I really thought I'd have found something on this, and maybe it's out there and I'm missing it. If that's the case I apologize and I'll close the question.

I'm checking to see if a modulo operation returns a result of zero, and I was wondering which of these is "better" (more pythonic, faster, whatever):

`if not count % mod`  **OR**  `if count % mod == 0`

I guess I should clarify and say that I have a very good understanding of truthy and falsey values, I just wanted to know if there was a concrete reason to use one over the other. Especially considering this is always going to be a number (otherwise the `%` operator would throw a TypeError).

Comment: It's the same, but second variant seems more readable.

Comment: It's not the same at all, as one tests for truthiness (or lack thereof) and one tests whether the answer is equal to zero or not.

Comment: Y'all are vicious with the downvotes today

Comment: Well the votes are so funny, 7 upvotes and 5 downvotes. So is this question good or not?

Comment: Mostly because even you yourself felt that you had to use scare-quotes around "better," which is a good indicator of a subjective, opinion-based question.

Comment: @KevinGuan Some say so, others say so...

Comment: @glglgl: Yeah, so that's the funny part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, the risk with using `not x` instead of `x==0` is that you might match another kind of value that is also falsey (for instance, `None` or an empty list).

In this case, since `x` must be a number, it is safe to use `not x` to mean `x==0`. Use whichever seems more readable.

To me, the first version looks a little odd, because I expect the results of an arithmetic operation to be treated like a number, so I would prefer the second version. But falseyness is there for convenience, and there are lots of circumstances it makes sense to make use of it.

Comment: Right, I understand some of the potential pitfalls of relying on truthy-ness, but I liked a comment on a deleted answer where he said "the question is really 'is count a multiple of mod?'" in which case it does seem to make sense to use `not`. I do like your point about expecting the result of a mod operation to be a number though

Answer (score 2):

From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Explicit is better than implicit.

In your case, you are explicitly checking for an integer value, the result of the modulo `%` operator, in which case you should test for `== 0`, not falsey values.

Comment: What's stopping this from being applied to all truthy and falsey values, rendering them taboo?

Comment: Nothing really, it is all subjective. In the case of doing math, it would look weird to check for `False` even though you technically could.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the diferences:

`if not foo` would be true for `foo = 0` and for `foo = ""` and for `foo = None`

`if foo == 0` would be true for `foo = 0` but not for `foo = ""` and `foo = None`

Comment: and for all "empty" objects (i. e. with zero length) that don't define `__nonzero__()` (or `__bool__()` in 3.x) and any object whose `__nonzero__()` (or `__bool__()` in 3.x) returns `False`.

Answer (score -1):

I would say use `x==0` as `not x` would also evaluate to true if `x = False`

Comment: Wasn't my down vote but probably because OP was asking about `%` which will never return `False`

Comment: Well, you could create a class defining a `__mod__` that returned boolean values, if you wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider these two cases:

```
count = 15
mod = 5

print count % mod == 0  # True
print not count % mod  # True
```

Everything seems fine. OK, so let's now break this code:

```
count = '%s'
mod = ''
print count % mod == 0  # False
print not count % mod  # True
```

As you can see - your two cases are not equivalent. It may be something worth to take into consideration.